# Visual Studio 2013 freezes whenever I edit any keyword

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For last few days i am having issue where Visual Studio 2013 freezes for 10 seconds whenever I edit any keyword. That is driving me crazy. I couldn't fine any resolution on how to fix it except turning off the IntelliSence. 
I have installed VS 2013 2 months ago and started happening after week or so. Then I installed the Update 4 and that fixed the issue, but the issue came back again. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed any extensions? If so, have you tried disabling/uninstalling them?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have installed some extensions like SQlite, PostSharp but none that will affect the editor.

Comment: PostSharp impacts the editor, it provides quickfix-like actions to apply aspects to classes, as well as coloring to indicate classes that have aspects applied to them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I guess PostSharp was causing the issue. I updated the PostSharp to newer version and that fixed the issue, If you post your comment I will mark it as answer. Thank you!